# AngularJS ng-repeat double rows

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to add a second row (`<tr>`) in the code below for each event in events in the ng-repeat. However, it only adds a single row at the end, I need each new row (class="info") to be BETWEEN each of the other rows with the rel attribute.

The cell in the info row will be filled via ajax and toggled when the Details link is clicked, it will then be toggled again when the Close link is clicked (Details changes to Close). It will work similar to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mrbaseball34/btwa7/

How would I do that in AngularJS?

```
<tbody id="events_tbody">
    <tr ng-repeat="event in events" rel="{{event.EVE_EVENT_CODE}}">
        <td>{{event.COURSE_TYPE}}</td>
        <td>{{event.EVE_FORMAL_DATE}}</td>
        <td>{{event.EVE_DESCRIPTION}}</td>
        <td>{{event.PRICE | dollars}}</td>
        <td class="nb">
            <a href="#">Details</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Now add Details row: -->
    <tr class="info" style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="5" id="info_{{event.EVE_EVENT_CODE}}"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make use of the special `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` attributes (explained [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)):

```
<tbody id="events_tbody">
    <tr ng-repeat-start="event in events" rel="{{event.EVE_EVENT_CODE}}">
        <td>{{event.COURSE_TYPE}}</td>
        <td>{{event.EVE_FORMAL_DATE}}</td>
        <td>{{event.EVE_DESCRIPTION}}</td>
        <td>{{event.PRICE | dollars}}</td>
        <td class="nb">
            <a href="#">Details</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Now add Details row: -->
    <tr ng-repeat-end class="info" style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="5" id="info_{{event.EVE_EVENT_CODE}}"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: When was that implemented because it doesn't work on my code. I'm using AngularJS v1.0.6

Comment: It's always annoying to figure out when stuff was added, as the docs don't mention anything about it.  The bright side is I bet you can upgrade to the 1.2.* series without anything breaking.

Comment: I added using the CDN and it worked but I've run across another issue.

Comment: Something that doesn't have to do with this. I have the main developer here and we're working it out.